# Display message whilst server is running query Django

Tags: html, django

I have a very long task that runs once the client/user/customer presses the submit button.  How can I display a message to say, hang on... query running, until the query finishes using Django?

Comment: Why not to enqueu the task? (In a thread, with celery, ....). (Sorry, I know that this is not expected answer. Response may be something like: show a loading message when 'submit button' is clicked, when request is received the new page overwride old one and 'loading message' is removed. Some ideas: http://thecrumb.com/2011/01/21/simple-loading-dialog-wjquery-ui/ )

Comment: Use frontend javascript to show a message when you submit. This sounds like the start of a bigger problem though and you should consider using an asynchronous solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing using JQuery and including some code to determine which button was pressed:

```
<form>
<div id="loading" style="display:none;">Finding all words, may take a long time</div>
<div id="form_input_things">
<input type="submit" name="_save" value="Save" />
<input type="submit" name="_get_words" value="Get Words" />
{{ form.as_p }}
</div>
</form>

<script>
    $("form").submit(function() {
    {
      if( $("[submit_button_pressed=Save]").get(0) === undefined )
      { 
        $('#loading').show();
        $('#form_input_things').hide();
      }
    }
    return true;    
    });

    $(":submit").live('click', function() {
       $(this).attr("submit_button_pressed", $(this).val());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This piece of code doesn't answer to your initial question. By the way, thanks for unaccepting my answer...

Comment: It does answer my question. Message appears and when query/submit returns the new page with the results is displayed.  It's also easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using Ajax to do that.

Let's see an example using JQuery;
If in your template, you have this form :

```
<form id="my_form" action="" method="post">
   <label for="age">Age:</label>
   <input type="text" name="age" id="age"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<div id="loading" style="display:none;">Loading...</div>
```

Let's write some Javascript, assuming you have already include the Jquery lib :

```
$(function(){
    $('#my_form').submit(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();

       alert('user submitted the form');
       $('#loading').show();

       $.post('my_url',
              {age : $('#age').val()},
              function(data){
                  $('#loading').hide();
                  alert('server finished to process data.');
              });
    });

});
```

You can fully customize this piece of code for doing what you want.
And if you want more debug in ajax, I suggest you to declare your ajaxSetup following this way :

```
function ajaxSetup(){

    $.ajaxSetup({
        error:function(x,e){
            if(x.status==0){
                alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
            }else if(x.status==404){
                alert('Requested URL not found.');
            }else if(x.status==500){
                alert('Internal Server Error.\n' + x.responseText);
            }else if(e=='parsererror'){
                alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
            }else if(e=='timeout'){
                alert('Request Time out.');
            }else {
                alert('Unknow Error.\n'+x.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @Martlark If you really want to use ajax with Django, checkout this project http://www.dajaxproject.com/ might be helpful :)

Comment: I'll have a try with dajaxproject when I stop falling asleep in the afternoons.

Comment: It sort of works, but runs into the problem of including all the form data and the cross site token thingo. I'm still working on it.